# Dependency issue upgrading laravel 4 package to laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am attempting to update a composer package for Laravel 5.  The Laravel 4 composer.json schema includes this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "illuminate/foundation": "4.*",
    "illuminate/support": "4.*"
},
```

I am attempting to update it to something like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "illuminate/foundation": "4.*",
    "illuminate/support": "5.*"
},
```

After running `composer install`, I got an error saying that `illuminate/foundation` could not be found, so I tried changing the `minimum-stability` to `dev`.  Composer can find the package now, but I get this error:

```
Problem 1
- illuminate/exception dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.4].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[dev-master, 5.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, dev-master].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.4, dev-master].
- illuminate/foundation 4.0.x-dev requires illuminate/exception dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/exception[dev-master].
- illuminate/foundation 4.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[dev-master].
- Installation request for illuminate/foundation 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/foundation[4.0.x-dev].
```

I need `illuminate/support` to be 5+ because of the changes in Laravel 5's service providers regarding config publishing.  I need `illuminate/foundation` because the unit tests require it.

**How can I structure these dependencies so composer can install them?**

I have tried also setting `illuminate/support` to `dev-master`, and both illuminate packages to `dev-master`, both resolving to different errors.  Is the only way to fix this to update upstream dependencies?

I have already gotten the updates to install and (seemingly) work correctly in a Laravel 5 installation. I may have worked around my issue by just making the entire `laravel/framework` a dependency, but I really don't think I want to leave that as the solution.

*Additional outputs from running composer install*

`illuminate/support` @ `dev-master` and `illuminate/foundation` at `4.*` :

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for illuminate/foundation 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/foundation[4.0.x-dev].
- illuminate/exception dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[dev-master, 5.0.x-dev].
- illuminate/foundation 4.0.x-dev requires illuminate/exception dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/exception[dev-master].
- Installation request for illuminate/support dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[dev-master].
```

`illuminate/support` @ `dev-master` and `illuminate/foundation` at `dev-master` :

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for illuminate/foundation dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/foundation[dev-master].
- illuminate/exception dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.0.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[dev-master, 5.0.x-dev].
- illuminate/foundation dev-master requires illuminate/exception dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/exception[dev-master].
- Installation request for illuminate/support dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[dev-master].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever use `dev-master` as version, just use `5.*` (for both packages) and you're ready.

Comment: I only switched to dev-master to see if anything would install, and if not what the reasoning composer gave would be.  I tried setting both to `5.*` with `minimum-stability` set to `dev` and I get `The requested package illuminate/foundation could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.` even after `composer clear-cache`. Taking minimum-stability out altogether gives the same result.

Comment: @watcher just looked at the repositories and saw that illuminate/support is deprecated, you should not use it. Why don't you just require `laravel/framework:5.*`?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I am not the maintainer of the package I am trying to update, so I was hoping to make as few changes as possible to the dependencies and thought I must be doing something wrong.